# AWS Cloudfront - S3 with CloudFront Origin Access and Referer bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have this settings on my s3 bucket policy, where I allow only my cloudfront and referer to access the files on the bucket. I also used Signed URL.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ABCD1234"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-files/*",
            "Condition":{
                "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":[
                    "https://example.com/*"
                ]}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And on the cloudfront behavior, I added the Referer here

[image]

Then, invalidate the cache.

Before setting the referer on s3 bucket policy, I can still access my files with signed url. But after setting up the `aws:Referer` Condition and invalidate the cache, I cannot access my files. It shows 403 Forbidden status.

What settings did I missed? Or is it possible to use Cloudfront OAI with Referer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What settings did I missed? Or is it possible to use Cloudfront OAI with Referer?

You **shouldn't use referrer**, as you use OAI. This means that CF will use AWS API to get your objects, not regular HTTP(s) requests. In that case `aws:Referer` is [not used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html):

> This key is included in the request context only if the request to the AWS resource was invoked by linking from a web page URL in the browser. This key is **not included for programmatic requests** because it doesn't use a browser link to access the AWS resource.

Comment: I see.. Thank you for that information. I just want to prevent users from accessing, for example image link, directly on the browser. Can cloud front do that? example users can't see the image if they put https://example.com/my-image.jpg on the browser. Image should be accessed only by the website.

Comment: @JSN Sady, you can't do this. You need proper authentication for that, where user login with username and password. OAI only ensures that your bucket is private, and no direct access to bucket is enabled. You could maybe setup CloudFront function to check the referrer header, but the header can be easily spoofed anyway.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Will take note of that.